# Scala Templates: Map a String to a Template

Tags: scala, scalate, scala-template

I use Scalate for templating. Usually it goes this way:

- Template:

  `Hello {{name}}`
- Parameters:

  `Map("name" -> "Peter")
- Result:

  `Hello Peter`

Is there a way to get the **Parameter Map as Result**?

- Template:

  `Hello {{name}}`
- Request:

  `Hello Peter`
- **Result:**

  `Map("name" -> "Peter")`

Comment: I don't think so. I also don't think your problem has a unique solution. Assume the template is `Hello {{name}} {{surname}}` and you've got `Hello Abc Def Xyz`. How do you know where the `name` ends and the `surname` starts?

Comment: I need it for an URL. So I think if you limit the parameter for just one path element, it will be possible - but you are right if you don't define some characters that are not allowed as parameters it's not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for regex with named groups?

```
//Regex with named groups
val pattern = """^Hello (?<firstname>\w+) (?<lastname>\w+)$""".r

val groups = List(
    "firstname",
    "lastname"
)

def matchAll(str: String): Option[Map[String, String]] = pattern
    .findFirstMatchIn(str)
    .map { matched =>
      groups.map(name => name -> matched.group(name)).toMap
    }

matchAll("Hello Joe Doe") //Some(Map(firstname -> Joe, lastname -> Doe))
```

Comment: thanks that looks as this could be a good start. However when I try to run it - it fails:
 https://scalafiddle.io/sf/CDcxsMZ/0 - did I miss something

Comment: Good to hear that